# Unable to iterate over collection in Backbone template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm new to coding in general and picking up Backbone together with Rails. My attempt to iterate collection data within a template has failed and I'm not sure what's wrong. When loading the webpage it seems that the json data and part of the template loads fine but the bit with the iteration fails. Here's the code:

acquisition.js:

```
var Acquisition = Backbone.Model.extend({
});
```

acquisitions.js:

```
var Acquisitions = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Acquisition,
  url: '/acquisitions.json'
});
```

acquisitions_index.js:

```
var AcquisitionsIndex = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "table",
    render: function() {
      this.$el.html(JST['acquisitions/index']({ collection: this.collection }));
      return this;
    }
});
```

index.jst.ejs:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Cash(USD)</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
  <% collection.each(function(model) { %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= model.escape('cashUSD') %></td>
    <td><%= model.escape('date') %></td>
  </tr>
  <% }); %>
</tbody>
```

home.html.erb:

```
<header>
  <h1>Startup acquisitions</h1>
</header>
  <div id="app"></div>
<script>
  var acquisitions = new Acquisitions;
  acquisitions.fetch();

  var acquisitionsIndex = new AcquisitionsIndex({collection: acquisitions});
  acquisitionsIndex.render();
  $("#app").append(acquisitionsIndex.el)
</script>
```

Comment: `fetch` is an AJAX call, the server hasn't responded when you try to use the collection so nothing useful happens. You need to bind to events from the collection and render in response to the events.

Comment: FYI, you can use `<%-` to automatically have Backbone escape values.

Comment: thanks @n3rd for the heads up. Is it relevant to the example in any way?

Comment: @batmanbegins No, it is not :) Just thought you might want to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put mu is too short's correct advice into an answer, it is important to understand that tha "A" in AJAX stands for asynchronous, which means that when you do a fetch, the client side JavaScript keeps on executing. It does not block and wait for the fetch to be returned. So while your code reads like:

1. Fetch collection
2. Receive collection items as response
3. Create view
4. Render collection in view :)

You are actually experiencing:

1. Fetch collection
2. Create view
3. Render empty collection in view :(
4. Receive collection items as response (What happened there?).

So as mu is to short comments, this is where events come into play. As an example you could amend your code block to be:

```
var acquisitions = new Acquisitions;
var acquisitionsIndex = new AcquisitionsIndex({collection: acquisitions});
acquisitionsIndex.listenTo(acquisitions, "sync", acquisitionsIndex.render);
acquisitions.fetch();
```

This code now means that the view is listening for the `"sync"` event on the collection, which signifies when the collection is successfully synced from the server. When the `sync` event occurs, the `render` function on the view is to be called as it is the last argument in the `listenTo` function. To ensure the view is inserted into the document, you might change your render function to:

```
render: function() {
    this.$el.html(JST['acquisitions/index']({ collection: this.collection }));
    $("#app").append(this.$el);
    return this;
}
```

Keep in mind that if your are chaining view render calls, its probably better to do document insertion `$("#app").append(this.$el);` after you have done all your chaining (to prevent multiple document reflows, however I put this line in your render function for simplicity in this example.

Comment: Hi dcarson thank you for the clear and concise explanation. It worked.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it helped. Feel free to upvote the answer when you get the Rep :)